# When i share image with text,text will move downwards in ios app?

Tags: ios, xcode5

Sir,
        I have awesome e cards app.I want to post the images with dynamic text via email.when i click on email in action sheet row.the image will post currectly but the text is moved position down wards.
    lable is used to display text on the image.lable is in clear color.for that i added font. we have a paints to draw a image for that we use drawimag obj.

```
     [fullImageViewObj addSubview:labelObj ];
        [fullImageViewObj addSubview:drawImage];
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef currentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 320, 440, 8, 0, colorSpace, (kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst));
        CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 440);
        CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
        [fullImageViewObj.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
        CGImageRef collageImg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(currentContext);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGContextRelease(currentContext);
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:collageImg]) writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

        switch (buttonIndex)
        {
        case Button_Index0:
            {
                MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;    

                if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
            {
                    [mail setSubject:@"MyImage - Name"];
                    NSString *emailBody = @"";
                    [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
                    [mail addAttachmentData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:collageImg]) mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"e-card.png"]; 
                    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
                [mail release];
            }
                break;
```

This is my ThirdScreenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nl1z.png

this is second screen Shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq2CW.png

Comment: the code you've attached is insufficient. did you try to display the view you are composing for making a screenshot?

Comment: when i try to display screen shot it asks 10 reputations how can i display.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tqsnl.png this is my screenshot.Please check once heximal

Comment: So, what's the problem? I don't quite understand. it doesn't look the same then displayed on screen and when rendered with CoreGraphics into png?

Comment: in second screen shot the mahesh is on 2015 and in third screen shot mahesh is bottom of the 2015.i am unable to add 3 screen shots.in first screen shot the hand buttom and Aa button disapper.mahesh is on image.

Comment: hi heximal do you understand issue.please check the second screen and third screen.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I was busy. I'll try to provide an alternative solution a bit later if it's not extremely urgent for you

Comment: Hi heximal ,fullImageViewObj is <UIImageView: 0xcb37fb0; frame = (0 48; 329 480);) may the size is the issue

Comment: Yes, definitely it may be an issue. Try to use imageview.size.width, imageview.size.height as the parameters when calling CGBitmapContextCreate instead of constant values (320, 440)

Comment: i tried fullImageViewObj.size.width,fullImageViewObj.size.height but it doest take.It takes fullImageViewObj.sizeto option that to it is an error

Comment: CGContextRef currentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, fullImageViewObj.Size.width ,fullImageViewObj.Size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, (kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 440);ERROR: Property 'Size' not found on object of type 'UIImageView *'